# How to render semi-transparent shadows on a shadow catcher?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, shadows

Hi I'm trying to render a shadow for a 2D sprite. I want it to be semi-transparent. I have a shadow-catcher plane, the object is invisible for the camera and my rendering engine is Cycles. However, right now the shadow is just black. How can I make it semi-transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I did not select Film->transparent.